# Does Electrical Travel Adapters Damage Circuits over long periods of time?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, adapter

I bought an electric shaver in Australia store, one of those larger Panasonic brands.

I want to use it at my residence in USA.

Does using Type I (Australia) or International,  to US adapter, over long periods of times destroy US Outlets or electrical system? Are there any side effects?

Just want to be sure, since the Electronic Device will be battery recharged everyday.

**Panasonic Shaver:**

[https://www.amazon.com/Panasonic-Electric-Flexible-Pivoting-ES-LV97-K/dp/B07W5SV5P8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07W5SV5P8)

[image]

**Travel Adapter Example:** Converts Australia back to US Outlet

**Adapters:**

[https://www.amazon.com/Ceptics-Canada-Travel-Plug-Adapter/dp/B0080SE6H2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0080SE6H2)

[https://www.amazon.com/ROAD-WARRIOR-Travel-Plug-Adapter/dp/B07BW17YD6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BW17YD6)

[image]

Comment: why was my question voted down? trying to learn

Comment: hi @isherwood this question is about electrical outlet damage to the home, not the appliance, I dont care about the appliance really, since its cheap

Comment: What reason do you have to think that _any_ small load on your circuitry would be damaging? What's the basis for your concern here?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Nothing UL-approved you plug into a circuit should be able to damage that circuit. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: you can convert an Australian 2 pin plug to American by twisting the pins using an adjustable wrench. however the manual says no to do this. "
• • Do not deface, modify, forcefully bend or pull
the cord or the power plug."

Answer (score 2):

No, you're fine. Presumably your device can auto detect the voltage (many can), but you'd wan to be sure. If it can't the device could be destroyed or catch fire, but the electrical system will be fine.

Comment: I agree. The travel adapter will be toast long before anything happens to the  U.S. outlet+1

Comment: Thanks, Jack.  I was actually thinking more of the device itself. The travel adapters might just be simple, hard wired adapters that could probably take quite a load.   Oddly enough as it may appear to some people, lower voltage (120) can be as harmful or more so to a device that's expecting 240 as can high voltage (240) be to a device that's expecting 120.

Comment: hi George, thanks for the answer, I just linked the Panasonic shaver device, its a battery rechargeable device, not sure if it changes the answer,

Answer (score 2):

No, certainly not the adapters you show in your photos. Those are nothing more than *physical* adapters, i.e. they provide electrical connections directly from their prongs to their outlet socket. If your device (e.g. the shaver) is able to charge properly using such adapters, then it already has the necessary electronics in it to convert the line voltage to whatever it needs and can accept a wide range of line voltage (e.g. both 120 V and 240 V, though I usually see ranges as as wide as a low of 100 V all the way through to 250 V, i.e. any voltage within that range would be acceptable). It won't affect the health of the electrical supply.

Even if the device cannot accept a range of voltages and you are forced to use a different type of adapter that actually *converts* the voltage (e.g. from US 120 V to a device's requirement of 240 V), that would also not in any way harm the electrical supply.

The only possible scenario that might be problematic at all is if the device (with or without required converter) draws more current than the wiring is rated for at the supply outlet. And if that were the case, there would typically be a circuit breaker, fuse, etc. that would disconnect the electricity before the supply wiring was damaged. I.e. in any residential or commercial wiring found in any modern building in any developed nation.

Comment: hi Peter, I just linked the Panasonic shaver device, its a battery rechargeable device, not sure if it changes the answer

Comment: No, it doesn't change the answer at all. While I couldn't tell the exact model from the photo, I'm very familiar with the general type of device.

Answer (score 2):

Really it would depend on the quality of the voltage converter, which is pretty hard to tell.

Another option might be to order the US adapter for the razor. https://amzn.to/2SyAHXq

Comment: so if I have a bad voltage converter, it would damage the circuits? not sure how to tell whats good, I'm just going for a really popular high reviewed brand on amazon, links above

Comment: Possible, but probably unlikely. But if it did it would likely just damage the shaver power supply. I can just sometimes be an advocate of doing things the right way rather than relying on unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

> the electronic device will be ***recharged*** everyday

You didn't link the actual product, but it really sounds like it's a ***battery-powered*** electric shaver.

Those use a "wall-wart" type power supply to convert 120 volts AC (which is a *lot*) into the low voltage the shaver/battery actually works on.    These days, most of those power supplies are "switching" (meaning electronic instead of transformer), and those tend to work on a wide range of voltages e.g. 100-240 volts.    The wall-wart will say for sure right on its label (which may be quite small).

If the wall-wart will accept 120V, then you can use a "dumb" adapter that is nothing but "wires".

However you should make sure to use a quality unit.  A lot of travel adapters are "Chinese cheapies" and their dangerously bad design is the stuff of legend.  In this space, almost anything on Amazon sold by a third party seller is Alibaba/eBay flea market junk, even if the price is not discounted.

Comment: hi Harpers, I just linked the Panasonic shaver device in question, its a battery rechargeable device